# Clean up an apache druid cluster

Tags: druid

Is there any way to clean up all the druid data (tasks, storage, etc.) for testing purposes?

Found the tutorial which demonstrates the segment deletion:

- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/data-management.html#delete

And reset-cluster tool:

- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/reset-cluster.html

My goal is to have a fresh druid cluster, every time I run testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking which of the two options to use, the reset-cluster tool will address your use case as it has options to remove metadata, task logs and segment data in deep storage. The `--all` option will remove all of them.

The segment deletion process, on the other hand, is used to remove unwanted segments from the cluster and deep storage, but does not address metadata in general or task logs.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run the reset command from a remote machine? In my use case, I'm running druid on k8s. I need to perform the command from my local machine.

Comment: I think the key phrase in the docs is this "So the java classpath used in the command must have all the necessary druid configuration files.". My understanding is that this means you can run it on your laptop as long as the configuration files have the info needed to access the cluster.